# ¿Es posible calcular el tamaño u espacio que ocupa en disco un Procedimiento Almacenado en SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Quisiera saber si es posible calcular el espacio que ocupan los distintos objetos dentro de una base de datos de SQL Server (a excepción de las tablas), estoy tratando de calcular el tamaño de un conjunto de base de datos y solo he podido hallar el tamaño de las tablas, mas no de los demás objetos.

Answer (score 1):

Con la consulta aquí abajo puedes obtener los tamaños, yo la uso muy seguido en mi trabajo  para saber el peso de los store procedures espero te sirva.

```
 SELECT o.type_desc AS [Tipo de Objeto]
        ,o.[name] AS [Nombre del objeto]
        ,DATALENGTH(m.definition) AS [Tamaño en Bites]
         ,(DATALENGTH(m.definition) / 1024 )as [Tamaño en KB]
             FROM sys.sql_modules AS m
INNER JOIN sys.objects AS o
    ON m.object_id = o.object_id
    where o.name='Nombre del Objeto'
```

Comment: La consulta es una versión *mejorada* de la respuesta realizada en SO en inglés http://stackoverflow.com/a/219740/3200493

Answer (score 1):

Sí es posible, el siguiente `query` te puede da información del espacio ocupado por  diferentes objetos en la base de datos como `Views`, `Triggers`, `Scalar Functions` y en efecto `Stored Procedures`:

```
SELECT name, Type,
   SUM(Chars)  SizeChars,
   SUM(Bytes)  SizeBytes,
   SUM(Bytes) / 1024. SizeKB
FROM
(
SELECT name, o.type_desc Type, 
       LEN(sm.definition) Chars,
       DATALENGTH(sm.definition) Bytes
    FROM sys.sql_modules sm
    JOIN sys.objects o ON sm.object_id = o.object_id
) x
GROUP BY name, Type
```