# ¿Qué vistas considerar para hacer un inventario de objetos en SQL Server 2008, sys.sysobjects o sys.objects?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

Tengo una duda sobre las estructuras al cuales debo recurrir para hacer un inventario de objetos dentro de una instancia (incluyen todas las bases de datos más las del sistema). Pero me he topado con algunas dificultades.

El primero es sobre a qué vistas consultar, si al **`[sys/dbo/null].sysobjects`**, que dicho sea de paso no sé por que funciona con ambos esquemas he incluso si no le especifico una, o el **sys.objects**. El hecho es que ambas opciones me arrojan la misma cantidad de objetos en todas las bases de datos mas no en el `master`. En el `master` la cantidad de objetos con la primera opción es 10 veces más (ejemplo: sysobjects: 2277 y sys.objects: 254).

Entonces si el inventario incluye la base de datos `master` voy a tener que elegir bien entre esas dos opciones y por qué.

El segundo problema es las distintas opciones dentro del *script* para la búsqueda de objetos. Para las tablas por ejemplo, he usado los esquemas de **`sys.table, sys.indexs`, `sys.allocation_units`**, etc, (también estoy calculando el tamaño que ocupan). para los procedimientos y vistas he usado **`information_schema.(tipo_objeto)`** y para las funciones he usado el **`sysobjects`**. Y por último encontré un `script` que me ayuda a calcular los tamaños de lo procedimientos y demás objetos haciendo consulta al **`sys.objects`**.

De modo que temo que la información de todo ese `script` no sea íntegra debido a los diferentes tipos de esquemas al cual hago consulta, mas aún habiendo comprobado que `sysobjects` y `sys.objects` arrojan datos distintos para el caso de `master`.

Culaquier sugerencia o ayuda será de mucha importancia.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En realidad, `sys.objects` es una versión más reciente de `sysobjects` (introducida en SQL Server 2000), para lo cual se recomienda que, en versiones superiores a SQL Server 2000 usar **`sys.objects`**.

La razón por la que existe un número mayor de objectos en `sysobjects`es debido a la retrocompatilibilidad, por ejemplo, si se requiere generar un *script* de una base de datos que actualmente se encuentra en SQL Server 2008 y deseas que sea para una versión de SQL Server 2000.

En esta [liga de MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187376(v=SQL.90).aspx) podrás ver las vistas de compatibilidad (*Compatibility Views*).

Para el segundo problema te recomiendo usar `sys.objects`. Un *script* con el cual ya había respondido anteriormente en [una pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/46196/16841), y que te puede ayudar justamente a encontrar aquellos objetos como `Stored Procedures`, `Views`, `Triggers` y `Scalar Functions`.

```
SELECT name, Type,
   SUM(Chars)  SizeChars,
   SUM(Bytes)  SizeBytes,
   SUM(Bytes) / 1024. SizeKB
FROM
(
SELECT name, o.type_desc Type, 
       LEN(sm.definition) Chars,
       DATALENGTH(sm.definition) Bytes
    FROM sys.sql_modules sm
    JOIN sys.objects o ON sm.object_id = o.object_id
) x
GROUP BY name, Type
```

Comment: Gracias, si, al parecer es mi pregunta, entonces consideraré la segunda opción, me imagino que el information_schema, o esquemas como sys.table, sys.index, etc "jala" la data del sys.object, de modo que no creo que haya problemas. Otra razón sobre la cantidad podría ser por que antes la BD master guardaba datos de las demás bases de datos ¿y ahora es más independiente? leía algo parecido con respecto a los esquemas sys y dbo relacionadas claro al sysobjects